# How to store a plain password in WordPress database in another field

Tags: database, password

Does anybody knows how could I get the plain password (via hook) in the moment a user registers and before it is hashed?
For example, when they are going to register a blog.

http://prntscr.com/k4sfbr

Note: i understand this is unethical, but i want to do a test and learn.

Thanks

Comment: But why? What do you want to learn with this experiment?

Comment: A totally new user with no reputation at all asking for information to basically hack/compromise WordPress!?! I think I"ll pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the password directly in the database, through phpmyadmin.

Comment: He wants to get the password, not to reset it...